# How can I implement a brick wall type layout to display a list ? - Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I want to display a list of genre as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbEzf.jpg)

I have an idea that I can make this by using recycler view + grid layout and customize the grid layout.

Further, I want to implement a click listener for each item.

1. Please suggest if (RV + grid layout) would be the best way to implement this layout.
2. if yes, then how can I customize the grid layout to look like this?
3. if no, please suggest better way to implement this.

Comment: Use [Chips](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) & `RecyclerView`.

Comment: use `FlexBoxLayoutManager` with Recycler View

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this layout using `RecyclerView` + `FlexBoxLayoutManager`.
For the individual item layout, I used Button, but any other layout such as text view, chips can also be used.
Thanks for the help